# shell script to search for a file and then echo contents of file

Tags: shell, grep, pipe

I am trying to to create a shell script to echo the contents of a file that I am not sure where to find it.

I thought it would be something like:

```
$echo | ls /* | grep file.xml
```

where my file could be in some unknown subfolder so I am trying to search for it's path with grep.

Any help on correct syntax would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find / -name file.xml -exec cat '{}' ';'
```

`/` says to look in `/` and its subdirectories; `-name file.xml` says to find files named `file.xml`; and `-exec cat '{}' ';'` says to run, e.g., `cat /path/to/file.xml` for each of those files, which prints out their contents.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to cat the file. Note that it will print all files if there are multiple matches. You may get permission errors you need to filter if you aren't sufficiently privileged. To avoid, only run on directories to which you have rights, execute with escalated privileges or use grep to remove them. Try:

```
cat `find / -name file.xml`
```

Comment: Re: "or use grep to remove them": Note that permission error-messages go to standard-error, so instead of using `grep` in some way, the logical way to suppress them is just `2>/dev/null`. Also, your command will misbehave if the path to `file.xml` contains any whitespace, question marks, or asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -lr "alice in wonderland" *
```

This will list all the files that contain text `alice in wonderland`. If you want to display the contents of each, do this:

```
grep -lr "alice in wonderland" *|while read filename; do
  echo ---- Contents of: "$filename"
  cat "$filename"
done
```